# angular-ui-router nested states "no such state" for parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm running into an issue setting the state of a nested view.

Here's the pertinent part of my test template which is being loaded into the 'main' ui-view on my index.html.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Header 1</li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#/test/page1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/test/page2">Page 2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Header 2</li>
        <li><a href="#/test/page3">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="container" ui-view="testcontent"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the js for my test module.

```
angular.module( 'test', [
    'ui.state',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'test.page1',
    'test.page2',
    'test.page3'
])

.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
    $stateProvider.state( 'test', {
        url: '/test',
        templateUrl: 'test/test.tpl.html',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'TestCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'test/test.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'Test' }
    })
    .state( 'test.page1', {
        url: '/page1',
        views: {
            "testcontent@test": {
                controller: 'Test1Ctrl',
                templateUrl: 'test/page1/page1.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'Test Page 1' }
    })
    .state( 'test.page2', {
        url: '/page2',
        views: {
            "testcontent@test": {
                controller: 'Test2Ctrl',
                templateUrl: 'test/page2/page2.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'Test Page 2' }
    })
    //.state( 'test.page3', {
    //    url: '/page3',
    //    views: {
    //        "testcontent@test": {
    //            controller: 'Test3Ctrl',
    //            templateUrl: 'test/page3/page3.tpl.html'
    //        }
    //    },
    //    data:{ pageTitle: 'Test Page 3' }
    //})
    ;
}) // Module configuration

.controller( 'TestCtrl', function TestCtrl( $scope ) {

});
```

This works fine if the config for the state is set up in the parent's module's config.

What I would like to do is set up the state in the module's config section rather than in the parent's.

```
angular.module( 'test.page3', [
    'ui.state',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'test'
])

.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
    $stateProvider.state( 'test.page3', {
        url: '/page3',
        views: {
            "testcontent@test": {
                controller: 'Test3Ctrl',
                templateUrl: 'test/page3/page3.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'Test Page 3' }
    });
}) // Module configuration

.controller( 'Test3Ctrl', function Test3Ctrl( $scope ) {

});
```

If I try this then my generic test for AppCtrl toBeTruthy blows up with an error "Failed to instantiate module test.page3 due to: No such state test".

Is there a way to do this or am I stuck chaining all of the .state() calls together in the test module?

Comment: There was a circular dependency problem in the modules so I'm giving lib3d credit for the answer.  Thanks!  I ended up needing test.page1, test.page2 and test.page3 in the dependencies for the test module and removed the dependency for test in each of the child modules.  I ended up updating angular-ui-router from ~0.0.1 to 0.2.10 which caused me to have to change ui.state to ui.router everywhere but it allowed me to move the state to the child's config section rather than chaining them all-together in the test module.

Comment: Thanks. But you should definitely reverse your deps tree and make it work. There is a difference between a child module that will provide services for your module to work and a child module that only plugs a page in your applicatiob hierarchy.

Comment: That was the only way I could get it to work.  When I tried to change the order around it couldn't find the route and sent me to .otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a problem: circular module dependency. `test` depends on `test.page3` which depends on `test`.

Then, the module using parent states of a parent module should depend on it.

Have the following module declarations:

```
angular.module( 'test', [
    'ui.state',
    'ui.bootstrap'
]);
```

and

```
angular.module( 'test.page3', [
    'test'
]);
```

And your `$stateProvider` configurations will work.

You should finally be able to have the same dependency structure for other pages.

Comment: This causes the error message to go away when I run my unit tests, but it seems like it's because it no longer tries to load that module.  When I click on the link to page3 now it's going to $urlRouterProvider.otherwise.  Also taking the dependencies of test.pageN out of the test module seems to break the angularjs binding so everything shows as {{foo}}.

Comment: In your unit test, you should load both modules (test and test.page3) for example. The dependency tree I presented here is the one I use in production with uirouter and it works fine. Except that I declare parent state with the `parent` state property instead of a state name prefix.

Comment: The unit test passes removing 'test.page3' from the dependencies of my test module.  What happens is when I click on the link for '#/test/page3' I'm being sent to $urlRouterProvider.otherwise rather than page3.  Changing the state to 'page3' and providing a parent state property makes no difference.  page1 and page2 work in the original code but only if I include the dependencies to 'test.page1' and 'test.page2'.

Comment: On a related side not, if you have a module with an abstract state like 'private' and then modules with nested states such as 'private.account, private.profile, etc.'. The above answer will also work in this situation if you include the app.private module in your app.accounts/nested stated modules.  Helped me a bunch.